# AWS VPC FlowLog - What is TCP Flag 6?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-application-load-balancer

I am getting TLS Negotiation Error on Public ALB.

To debug this, I initiated Curl Request to my public ALB using curl with older TLS Version.

I did not get anything on ALB Access Logs.

So I checked in VPC Flow Logs. I found that all requests are accepted.

However in TCP Flag field, I am getting number 6.

As per AWS Documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html, there are only 4 TCP Flags:

```
FIN — 1
SYN — 2
RST — 4
SYN-ACK — 18
```

So what is TCP Flag 6 in VPC Flow Log? and is it related with TCP Negotiation Error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the documentation you linked has been updated since you posted this question. It now includes the following text:

> TCP flags can be OR-ed during the aggregation interval. For short connections, the flags might be set on the same line in the flow log record, for example, 19 for SYN-ACK and FIN, and 3 for SYN and FIN. For an example, see TCP flag sequence.

In other words, the `tcp-flags` are [bit masks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)) meaning they can be combined to create unique numbers. These combinations happen when multiple requests occur within the "aggregation interval" of the flow logs.

Therefore, a `6` is going to be a combination of `4 + 2` since two records were combined into a single, aggregated record. So you received two messages, a `SYN` and a `RST`.

For more information about the aggregation interval, check out the "Aggregation interval" section of the ["Logging IP traffic using VPC Flow Logs"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html#flow-log-records) article.